# Least squares method for parameter estimation in AR(1) model

Tags: time-series, self-study, least-squares, autoregressive

In order to estimate parameters $ \mu $ and $ \alpha$ least squares method can be used.  This is what I did to find the least squares.
$$
S=\sum_{t=2}^n(X_t-\mu-\alpha X_{t-1}+\alpha\mu)^2
$$.
And took ${\partial S \over \partial \mu}=0$ and ${\partial S \over \partial \alpha}=0$ .

From

${\partial S \over \partial \mu}=0$
 I got

$(\hat \alpha-1)\sum_{t=2}^nX_t -\hat \alpha(\hat
 \alpha-1)\sum_{t=2}^nX_{t-1}-\hat \mu(n-2)(\hat \alpha -1)(1-\hat
 \alpha)$

.
My problem is can I **divide** this equation by $(\hat \alpha -1)$?This is possible if AR process is stationary because then $-1<\alpha<1$.

Supposing this was possible I found $\hat \alpha $ to be :

> ${(n-2)\sum_{t=2}^nX_tX_{t-1}+\sum_{t=2}^nX_t\sum_{t=2}^nX_{t-1}\over{(\sum_{t=2}^nX_{t-1})^2-(n-2)\sum_{t=2}^nX_{t-1}^2}}$

I would like to know if I can suppose the series is stationary so that i can divide by  $(\hat \alpha -1)$ and whether my $\hat \alpha$
 expression is correct?

Comment: I would suppose the series to be stationary. (You might want to ponder what happens when you don't have it.)

Comment: OLS is an algebraic method, and the OLSE is well-defined irrespective of whether $\alpha$ is less than one or not. Try `Y <- cumsum(rnorm(100))` and `lm(Y[2:100]~Y[1:99])`.
Its statistical properties depend on the value of $\alpha$, though.